# clearing errors in an ActionErrors object

Tags: java, struts

is there a way to remove a specific error from an ActionErrors object? For example, I managed to find out that `errors.size("specialCode") > 0`, where `ActionErrors errors` is the object, how do i remove the message `specialCode`?

this is struts 1.0, java jdk 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `get(String property)` returns an `Iterator`, which you can loop and remove all messages.

```
for (Iterator iterator = errors.get("specialCode"); iterator.hasNext();) {
  iterator.next();
  iterator.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There is only a [`ActionErrors.clear()`](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/api/org/apache/struts/action/ActionMessages.html#clear%28%29) method, which clears all messages record in the object.